# how to translate hardcoded messages in program vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I need to convert my vb.net program to a MultiLanguage program.
It's cler how to translate the GUI and allow the user to change the Language.. what is not clear tough, is how to translate all the hardcoded message boxes.. Is there some sort of translation table where I can write the translated text for each Language, or do I need to replace all the messages by variables and the set a different value vor the variable based on the Language?

Comment: what platform? is it web, mobile, desktop, etc? please add tags

Comment: the most common way to make an application multi-language is using resource files (e.g. buttons.language-es-mx.resx, buttons.language-it.resx are two files for button label texts in Spanish-Mexico and Italian) and depending on current culture (CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) you retrieve translation from one file or the other file. The variable that identifies a text is the resourceKey

Comment: thank you @derloopkat, could you please elaborate on how to do it and post it as answer? thank you!

Comment: It's not up to us to teach you something like that. We're here to help with specific issues. You need to do some research on Globalization, which is making your app able to handle multiple languages, and Localization, which is making it support a specific language.

Comment: he just realized that he need a multi-language app and doesn't want to create the resources file. When you target many languages you need to think about it in the beginning, specially if you are going to write something big like 20 000 lines. It's a lot job to create the string for each resource. If you do them as you go then to translate your resources files you could at least run it through a translator.